# How to import data from EXCEL to PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, excel, cplex, opl

Cplex OPL:

```
SheetConnection file("DATA.xlsx"); 
v from SheetRead(file, "Set1!C2:F4");
f from SheetRead(file, "Set1!C7:F9");
u1 from SheetRead(file, "Set1!C13:F16");
u2 from SheetRead(file, "Set1!J13:M16");
u3 from SheetRead(file, "Set1!P13:S16");
C from SheetRead(file, "Set1!C21:F23");
MOQ from SheetRead(file, "Set1!C27:F29");
D from SheetRead(file, "Set1!B42:D42");  
strat from SheetRead(file, "Set1!C33:F35");
```

The above Cplex data file describes how i import data from excel to Cplex. And i want to do the same with Python. I tried to use Pandas and i did wrong somewhere so it not worked at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont forget to install pandas first using pip

```
import pandas as pd

# Load Excel file into pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel('DATA.xlsx', sheet_name='Set1', header=None)

# Access data in DataFrame
v = df.iloc[1:4, 2:6].values.tolist()
f = df.iloc[6:9, 2:6].values.tolist()
u1 = df.iloc[12:16, 2:6].values.tolist()
u2 = df.iloc[12:16, 9:13].values.tolist()
u3 = df.iloc[12:16, 15:19].values.tolist()
C = df.iloc[20:23, 2:6].values.tolist()
MOQ = df.iloc[26:29, 2:6].values.tolist()
D = df.iloc[41, 1:4].tolist()
strat = df.iloc[32:35, 2:6].values.tolist()

# Print data
print(v)
print(f)
print(u1)
print(u2)
print(u3)
print(C)
print(MOQ)
print(D)
print(strat)
```